# How to avoid dangling reference with R-value

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Some discussion warns about dangling reference, with R-Value reference. I do not see any dangling reference in the following example as DTOR was called when main() terminates. Am I missing something?

```
class test_ctor
{
public:
explicit
test_ctor(int x = 1):_x(x)
{
    std::cout << "CTOR: " << _x << "\n";
}

~test_ctor()
{
    std::cout << "DTOR: " << _x << "\n";
}

test_ctor(test_ctor const & y) = default;

test_ctor(test_ctor && y) = default;
int _x;
};

test_ctor test_rvalue()
{
test_ctor test = test_ctor(2);
return test;
}
```

Now I can use the above code in two ways:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
auto test = test_rvalue();
std::cout << " test: " << test._x << " \n";
return 0;
}
```

Or

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
auto && test = test_rvalue();
std::cout << " test: " << test._x << " \n";
return 0;
}
```

both case has the same output:

> CTOR: 2
>
> test: 2
>
> DTOR: 2

Which means both are efficient ways to return object. Are there any side effects in r-value reference?

Comment: Nothing dangles here. The two approaches are identical (in this case at least).

Comment: You don't return anything but value here. ***A side effect is a result of an operator, expression, statement, or function that persists even after the operator, expression, statement, or function has finished being evaluated.*** Rvalue reference use isn't any of those. The premise of "discussions" is unknown and your problem is unclear so far.

Answer (score 2):

In [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11):

`auto test = test_rvalue();` moves the return value of `test_rvalue()` into `test`.  This move is then *elided* by every non-brain damaged compiler so it never happens.  The move constructor still needs to exist, but is never called, and any side effects of moving do not occur.

`auto&& test = test_rvalue();` binds an rvalue reference to the temporary returned by `test_rvalue()`.  The temporaries lifetime is extended to match that of the reference.

In [c++17](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b17):

`auto test = test_rvalue();` the prvalue return value of `test_rvalue()` is used to directly construct the variable `test`.  No move, elided or not, occurs.

The `auto&&` case remains unchanged from [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

Comment: @SyedRaihan Note that lifetime extension only applies to to direct binding of a temporary to a reference outside of an object's constructor initializer list.  So here be dragons.

Comment: @SyedRaihan It is neither useful nor appropriate to name and shame people here, regardless of their (perceived) level of engineering or management skill.

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger I agree. I feel sorry.